# Deploying Typescript Express.js App Exit status 127

Tags: typescript, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy an express app onto Heroku, yet it keeps crashing with an exit error of 127. From the logs it seems that the error is using the "tsc" command when I run build ("build": "tsc --build tsconfig.json"). However, tsc is in my "node_module/.bin" directory and node modules is not ignored in my .gitignore file. Here are my heroku logs:

```
2023-07-20T01:29:55.188499+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run start`
2023-07-20T01:29:56.776422+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-20T01:29:56.776448+00:00 app[web.1]: > cse331-hw-draft-server@0.0.1 prestart
2023-07-20T01:29:56.776448+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run build
2023-07-20T01:29:56.776448+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-20T01:29:57.013771+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-20T01:29:57.013773+00:00 app[web.1]: > cse331-hw-draft-server@0.0.1 build
2023-07-20T01:29:57.013775+00:00 app[web.1]: > tsc --build tsconfig.json
2023-07-20T01:29:57.013775+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-20T01:29:57.018399+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: tsc: not found
2023-07-20T01:29:57.027957+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice
2023-07-20T01:29:57.028039+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.6.7 -> 9.8.1
2023-07-20T01:29:57.028101+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.8.1>
2023-07-20T01:29:57.028356+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.8.1` to update!
2023-07-20T01:29:57.028446+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice
2023-07-20T01:29:57.180374+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2023-07-20T01:29:57.208024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I also have some errors with GET "/" and "/favicon.ico if that could be explained. How should I go about fixing these issues?

```
2023-07-20T01:35:41.238633+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=spot-game-server-6466748a1653.herokuapp.com request_id=30fe7b3f-fc2d-4d92-98a6-03f3189c1565 fwd="99.119.67.14" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-07-20T01:35:41.481577+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=spot-game-server-6466748a1653.herokuapp.com request_id=bfd5b97c-bcc0-408a-885b-d12126615c6d fwd="99.119.67.14" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I have tried using "npx tsc --build tsconfig.json" but that results in an exit error of 1 and these Heroku logs:

```
: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-07-20T01:25:31.733185+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run start`
2023-07-20T01:25:33.254086+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-20T01:25:33.254093+00:00 app[web.1]: > cse331-hw-draft-server@0.0.1 prestart
2023-07-20T01:25:33.254093+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run build
2023-07-20T01:25:33.254093+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-20T01:25:33.486287+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-20T01:25:33.486288+00:00 app[web.1]: > cse331-hw-draft-server@0.0.1 build
2023-07-20T01:25:33.486289+00:00 app[web.1]: > npx tsc --build tsconfig.json
2023-07-20T01:25:33.486289+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-20T01:25:34.076053+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: tsc@2.0.4
2023-07-20T01:25:34.243151+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-20T01:25:34.243480+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                                                
2023-07-20T01:25:34.243507+00:00 app[web.1]:                 This is not the tsc command you are looking for                
2023-07-20T01:25:34.243527+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                                                
2023-07-20T01:25:34.243546+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-20T01:25:34.243564+00:00 app[web.1]: To get access to the TypeScript compiler, tsc, from the command line either:
2023-07-20T01:25:34.243564+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-20T01:25:34.243582+00:00 app[web.1]: - Use npm install typescript to first add TypeScript to your project before using npx
2023-07-20T01:25:34.243596+00:00 app[web.1]: - Use yarn to avoid accidentally running code from un-installed packages
2023-07-20T01:25:34.268029+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice
2023-07-20T01:25:34.268084+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.6.7 -> 9.8.1
2023-07-20T01:25:34.268129+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.8.1>
2023-07-20T01:25:34.268302+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.8.1` to update!
2023-07-20T01:25:34.268393+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice
2023-07-20T01:25:34.389241+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-07-20T01:25:34.418714+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I have also reinstalled typescript and removed the node_modules from my .gitignore file but still crash with either the 127 or 1 exit code.

Comment: The package is called typescript not tsc. Read through the error messages and you will see.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Later in my question I talk about how I reinstalled typescript and the error still persisted, or is this not the same

Comment: Delete the lock files created by your package manager and remove the tsc package from your  package.json. In your build script, use `npm install && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --build tsconfig.json`